# Yii RESTful authentication

Tags: php, rest, authentication, yii

I am having trouble finding a method for authenticating API users in my application. I set out to initially build a system that users could access and authenticate through the web, but requirements have changed and I need to implement some additional actions that can be available in a RESTful manner using a POST API call.

I have created a class that extends `CBehaviour` and forced a redirect to the login page for all unauthenticated users ([found on the yii framework forum here](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/23438-redirect-to-login-for-guest-users-in-every-controller/)). Problem is that all API calls are forced through the same logic and any POST requests simply spit out the HTML to the login page.

```
class ApplicationBehavior extends CBehavior {
    private $_owner;

    public function events() {
        return array(
            'onBeginRequest' => 'forceGuestLogin',
        );
    }

    public function forceGuestLogin() {
        $owner = $this->getOwner();
        if ($owner->user->getIsGuest())
            $owner->catchAllRequest = array("site/login");
    }
}
```

How would I go about separating the authentication of API users from the Web users?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would follow this [guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/175/how-to-create-a-rest-api/) on creating a REST API in Yii.  After modifying the config urlManager entries, all of your API requests will use the APIController.  You can then place the following code in the beforeAction of your APIController to return nothing if the user is a guest (Or an error message)

```
protected function beforeAction($event) {
    if (Yii::app()->user->isGuest) {
        echo "Invalid credentials";
        Yii::app()->end();
    }
}
```

Note:  The code above works for my purposes because all REST requests are sent via the same browser. (Which is already logged in and has a login cookie)

If you replace that behavior with a new base controller placed in `protected/controllers` to force login, it will only apply to your pages that require a login and not your APIController.  Here is an example of mine:

```
//Make sure all Controllers which require a login inherit from this
class ControllerLoginRequired extends CController {
    public function runAction($action) {
        if (Yii::app()->user->isGuest && 'site' != $this->route) {
           Yii::app()->user->returnUrl = $this->route;
           parent::redirect(array('site/login'));
        } else {
           parent::runAction($action);
        }
    }
}
```

Everything explained will work for REST requests via the same browser in which the user has logged onto Yii.  If you will have the need to expose your REST service to consumers that are not a browser logged into Yii, I believe you would have to come up with a custom authentication/token scheme.

Comment: Yes I have already gathered some code from that tutorial, it's pretty much the only one out there explaining REST APIs in Yii and EVERYONE refers you to it. The problem still stands that my extension of CBehavior which forces guest login will override anything in this API controller because it's executed before it.

Comment: Instead of using a behavior to redirect to login I use a LoginRequiredController that is inherited by all controllers that require a login.  If you do it this way, you could solve that problem at least.  The APIController for REST would not inherit from that one.

Comment: On a side note since it isn't mentioned, you can place this inside `protected/components` so it will be auto-loaded (since controllers aren't auto-loaded by default) and you won't have to import it in all your controllers that need to extend it.

Comment: That is where mine currently is located to make use of the php autoload.  I updated that point in the answer.

Comment: I just fixed a bit of the code, trying to access the login page would result in an infinite loop of redirects.

Comment: Thanks Matt.  Just an FYI though.  The `&& 'site' != $this->route` is not required on mine and it doesn't cause an infinite redirect loop.  Not sure what is different about yours.

Comment: Maybe the custom behavior you spoke of in the OP is still active?

Comment: My site controller extends the `LoginRequired` class as well, and guests are redirected to 'site/login' if they are not authenticated... which will trigger the same redirect logic to happen infinitely.